# Will iphone app get rejected if metadata uses an unsupported language?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

If the app title and description is in an unsupported language (e.g. Philippino), but the language chosen in iTunes connect is in English (because there is no options to select Philippino), will the app get rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I submitted a few applications in Polish, with English selected as a language, and they were accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Submit it! What's the worst that could happen? It'd probably be metadata rejected which means there isn't a problem with the app, just with the description etc.